# Whats the best way to setup & populate my nstableview with json data?

Tags: json, xcode5, nstableview

I'm sorry if this has already been answered. I'm a bit of a noob. From all the examples I've found I can't seem to work this out.

I'm building a mac osx application using Xcode 5. My interface that I've created in Interface builder has three tableviews. My data to populate these views is json format and it is being received successfully using NSURLConnection.

What is the best way to popular the tableviews? A lot of the tutorials I've followed use an arraycontroller that is dragged and dropped using IB. From what I understand I don't need an array controller and need to hand code controllers for each of tableviews. Is that correct? If so, please explain how I go about this and setup the bindings.

Also, when clicking on a column in tableview 1 I'm planning on making it adjust the data in tableview 2 & 3 so if that impacts anything please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

**Update 6 Jan**

Here is my code currently..

ContactsTableViewController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ContactsTableViewController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet NSTableView *contactsTableView;
}


-(id) init;

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView;

-(NSView *) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;

@end
```

ContactsTableViewController.m

```
#import "ContactsTableViewController.h"

@implementation ContactsTableViewController

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInTableView called");
    return 1;
}

- (id) init {
    NSLog(@"init called");

    [contactsTableView setDelegate:self];
    [contactsTableView setDataSource:self];

    [contactsTableView reloadData];

    return self;
}

- (void) initme {
    NSLog(@"customfunc");
}



-(NSView *) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSLog(@"viewForTableColumn called");

    NSTextField *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"name" owner:self];// result is now guaranteed to be valid,

    result.stringValue = @"My Name"; //[self.nameArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return result;

}


@end
```

In my appDelegate:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    NSLog(@"AWAKE");

    ContactsTableViewController *contactsController = [[ContactsTableViewController alloc] init];
}
```

Currently nothing is showing in the tableview and numberOfRowsInTableView & viewForTableColumn aren't getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UITableViewDataSource, you need to implement the protocol in one of your classes, probable your view controller, implement the UITableViewDelegate to get row selection events in the same class.